# decomposition of an orthogonal matrix 

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi,

I have a matrix : $W=I+U^TV$

- $dim(W)=(D,D)$
- $dim(U)=dim(V)=(N,D)$ with $N < < D$

I need it to be orthogonal ie $W^TW=I$

which gives me : $V^TU+U^TV+V^TUU^TV=0$

From that point, i don't know where to go. Have anyone got some ideas about that issue ?

Cheers

Guillaume

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment. I think this question is not apt here. You should consider posting questions  like these at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Given $U$ and if it is full rank, we can choose $$V = -2 \left(UU^T \right)^{-1}U$$ and the matrix $$W = I - 2 U^T \left(UU^T \right)^{-1}U$$ is an orthonormal matrix. A special case of this is provided by Jeff.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a general solution or simply a good family of examples? If you want examples, let $V=-U=\sqrt{2} S^T$ where $S$ is an isometry from $\mathbb{R}^N$ into $\mathbb{R}^D$.